# uploaded multiple IFC file on forge viewer but positions are not correct

Tags: javascript, .net, autodesk-forge, translate, viewer

uploaded multiple IFC file on forge viewer but positions are not correct (using JobSvfOutputPayloadAdvanced.ConversionMethodEnum.Modern).but files are not align.

Comment: Could you share more problem details (e.g snapshots of correct and incorrect positions)? if it cannot be posted publicly, please consider sharing non-confidential reproducible IFC models demonstrating this issue to `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` for investigations?